# XML accessible from URL line but not from script

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

When I type a certain URL in FF, I get the XML returned displayed on the screen, so the web service is apparently working. However, when I try to access it from a local HTML document running JS, I get unexpected behavior. The returned code is "200 OK" **but** there's no text (or rather it's an empty string) nor xml (it's `null`) in the response sections according to FireBug.

This is how I make the call.

```
var httpObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpObject.open("GET", targetUrl, true);
httpObject.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (httpObject.readyState == 4) {
    var responseText = httpObject.responseText;
    var responseXml  = httpObject.responseXML;
  }
}
httpObject.send(null);
```

Why does it happen and how do I tackle it?

Comment: Is it in the same domain? If not, you have to use JSONP for cross-domain requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may be an HTTP header problem (e.g. missing `Accept` header); observe the headers sent by FF (you can use Firebug for that) and try to replicate them in your script (`setRequestHeader`).

Otherwise, that may be a "same origin policy" problem.